# Having issues casting from const void * to template type with LLVM

Tags: c++, templates, casting, llvm, void-pointers

I am having problems compiling the following function with LLVM which compiles perfectly fine in MSVC.

```
template<typename Fn>
Fn GetVFunction(const void *instance, std::size_t index) {
    const auto vtable = *reinterpret_cast<const void***>(const_cast<void*>(instance));
    return reinterpret_cast<Fn>(vtable[index]);
}
```

The following error happens:

> ```
>  "reinterpret_cast from 'const void *' to 'SDK::UObject *(*)(SDK::UClass *)' casts away qualifiers"
> ```

I looked around and it was suggested to do the following-

```
return const_cast<Fn>(reinterpret_cast<const Fn>(vtable[index]));
```

Which resulted in the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You do a `const_cast<void*>(instance)`. How come this error isn't clear to you?

Comment: Without that it errors with reinterpret_cast from 'const void *' to 'const void ***' casts away qualifiers. Basically same problem just earlier in the code. The original error occurred on the final line.

Comment: "*Which resulted in the same problem*" - that's impossible. Show us the error in that second case.

Comment: I did, read my message again. " reinterpret_cast from 'const void *' to 'const void ***' casts away qualifiers"

Code: const auto vtable = *reinterpret_cast<const void***>(instance);

Comment: `const auto vtable = *reinterpret_cast<const void***>(const_cast<void*>(instance));` What do you expect `vtable` should be after this line?

Comment: The VTable needs to be a void** or else you cannot access it at index due to "subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'const void'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem occurs at template instantination, your error is no reproducible, but I would think that the following should work

```
template<typename Fn>
Fn GetVFunction(const void *instance, std::size_t index) {
    auto vtable = reinterpret_cast<void**>(const_cast<void*>(instance));
    return reinterpret_cast<Fn>(vtable[index]);
}
```

Note that `void*` manipulations are usually a sign of poor coding in C++ (because it is error prone), but common in C (which lacks type-safe generic programming)

Comment: instance needs to be dereferenced so I changed it to \*reinterpret_cast<void***> and that seems to have worked.
I now see the error after trying your solution. I guess LLVM does not like doing reinterpret_cast to const void* and in this case, it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @TJ8 You still don't seem to understand the original error. LLVM complained about the second `reinterpret_cast`, when you attempted to cast from a `const` to a non-`const` pointer. That MSVC allows this is a BUG.